# Is it possible to shorten custom view names?

Tags: android, android-view, android-xml

Let's say that I created a custom view called `MyView` and want to use it in the xml and the view is located in `com.example` package. I need to do something like this:

```
<com.example.MyView
   ......
/>
```

I need to write the package name *every* time I use the view. What if I have a long package name?

```
<what.a.long.long.long.loooooong.packagename.MyView
   ......
/>
```

That just looks ugly. Is it possible to shorten the package name? Do I need to do something in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: sure: you can use anything, like for example `custom.MyView` and use `LayoutInflater#setFactory[2]`

Comment: @pskink Can you explain the solution a bit more or post it as an answer?

Comment: by inplementing `Factory` / `Factory2` interface you can create your custom views in `onCreateView`, javadocs say:  **"Hook you can supply that is called when inflating from a LayoutInflater. You can use this to customize the tag names available in your XML layout files."**

Comment: I don't know how to implement the interfaces. So I'm still waiting for an answer

Comment: and what did you try?

Comment: so if you did not try anything, i can not help you much...

Comment: @pskink I highly doubt your comment answers his question. What are you expecting him to do with such a short and vague comment?

Comment: @JaredRummler what do i expect from him? just to read the `LayoutInflater` documentation... is it too much?

Comment: @JaredRummler yes it is, read about `LayoutInflater.Factory` and `LayoutInflater.Factory2` interfaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your own namespace:

```
<Layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:x="what.a.long.long.long.loooooong.packagename."
    >
    <x:MyView>
    </x:MyView>
</Layout>
```

`xmlns:x` spefifies that all tags that start with `<x:` should be looked up in package that is defined in the namespace definition (`what.a.long.long.long.loooooong.packagename.` in this case).

You can even use the namespace within the tag itself:

```
<x:MyView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:x="what.a.long.long.long.loooooong.packagename."
    />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use my library [XmlTag](https://github.com/blipinsk/XmlTag). It lets you use short name of every `View` that you annotate with `@XmlTag`.

[image: XmlTag in action]

Comment: Too bad it is not maintained anymore.